# Split data of a row in multiple rows

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-forms, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

I've got some problem with data coming from a Google form.

The result are:

```
A|A|A|A|B|B|B|B|C|C|C|C|
```

What I want to get is:

```
A|A|A|A|
B|B|B|B|
C|C|C|C|
```

Is there a way to get a similar result?

Comment: Is the data always in groups of 4? Could the data ever be: `A|A|A|B|B|B|C|C|C`?

Answer (score 1):

```
={A1:D1; E1:H1; I1:L1}
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=QUERY({A1:D; E1:H; I1:L}, "where Col1 is not null", 0)
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(LEN(A1:A), 
 {"♠"&A1:A&"♦", B1:D&"♦", "♠"&E1:E&"♦", F1:H&"♦", "♠"&I1:I&"♦", J1:L&"♦"}, ))
 , , 999^99)), , 999^99), "♠")), "♦"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Sorry for my poor knowledge, what are the meanings of the symbols?

Comment: no real meaning. its just a unique symbol/character for SPLIT formula to separate stuff on that exact spot

Comment: @Fav https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers